# Save a partial structure

Tags: c

I have a structure like this:

```
struct DATOS{
  short dato1;
  float dato2;
};

DATOS dat1;
dat1.dato1 = 123;

FILE *archivo;
archivo = fopen("archivo.bin","wb");
fwrite(&dat1,sizeof(DATOS),1,archivo);
fclose(archivo);
```

Fine but if I want to enter after the other value, How do I do it?

dat1.dato2 = 4.2536;

```
archivo = fopen("archivo.bin","ab");
fwrite(&dat1.dato2,sizeof(float),1,archivo); ????
fclose(archivo);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `DATOS dat1;` is wrong as it is currectly written. either use `typedef` for the structure  or use `struct` in the variable definition

Comment: Seconding the point by @SouravGhosh, but the alternative is: don't use a C++ compiler for compiling C; it will allow such things to 'work', even though they are not valid C.

Comment: Do you want to append extra structures to the file, or do you want to overwrite just part of the one structure that's already in the file?  If you want to append, you need to write a whole new structure; otherwise, you've no real way of knowing that there's an `short` and a `float` (plus optional padding), followed by a `float`, in the file, so there isn't a good way to read the data back in again.  For both overwriting and appending, handling the whole structure is far easier.

Comment: Yes, I want to overwrite just part of the one structure. Yes I think the best is to overwrite the entire structure. Thank you very much friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in your pseudo-code, the first fwrite() will write a copy of the entire structure to the file, with dato2 being garbage at that point.

Your later fwrite() will append a copy of dato2 to the file.  So, in the file it will look something like:

struct DATOS (with garbage for dato2)
float

If you want to overwrite just the garbage dato2 later with actual data, then you should do something like:

```
archivo = fopen("archivo.bin", "r+b");
fseek(archivo, (long) ((char*) &dat1.dato2 - (char*) &dat1), SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&dat1.dato2, sizeof(dat1.dato2), 1, archivo);
fclose(archivo);
```

Comment: Mmm, but using the modifier "wb" erase entire file, does not it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code would append the binary representation of the `float` value `dato2`.

There's no need to close and re-open the file inbetween of course, you could just do both `fwrite()`s in sequence, then close the file.

Also, this:

```
fwrite(&dat1.dato2, sizeof(float), 1, archivo);
```

is better written as

```
fwrite(&dat1.dato2, sizeof dat1.dato2, 1, archivo);
```

That makes it work regardless of the type of `dato2`.

Note that storing binary values like this makes the file quite non-portable, since the exact contents will depend a lot on the host computer that wrote it.

Comment: I think maybe the questioner wants to overwrite updated part of the structure in the file. He'll need to use `fseek()` and the often overlooked `offsetof()` macro (`#include <stddef.h>`) to do what I think he's doing.

Comment: Good, but imagine that these two fragments are in different parts of a program. Therefore, should be opened at different times.